# Lock application window movement on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

Sometimes, when I use touchpad to control cursor and I'm clicking or double clicking, I move the application window a few pixels because my finger does not tap the touchpad on one place.

**Is there a way (Mac OS X) to lock application window, so that it can't be moved with cursor unless unlocked again?**

Is there another way to solve this? (Besides me being more careful when double clicking...)

Is there even an attribute of "window object" that can lock it's position? I can try to write an App that handles just that (or a script run every time I run Application which I want to lock windows for). If there isn't would an OS X Application that "watches" windows movements and counters them (moves back) be hard to code?

Answer (score 1):

Afloat http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

Comment: Afloat is a great app, but it can't disable window movement. For making windows stick over others, or under them, it's great (I love the transparency tools too).

Comment: It isn't perfect, but if you make it Afloat (above others), and an overlay (clicks go through), now you cannot move it. If being on top is annoying, make it invisible when you aren't interacting with it.

Comment: My point is to use that window, not only let it hover over the others. I want to click on it, interact with it, but setting it to "overlay" makes the exact opposite. Other problem with Afloat is, that it's not available for every window. It's a great app, but does not solve my problem.